# how to store tuple value as python variable

Tags: python

I am fetching mysql select statement as a tuple. How do I extract 0 or 1 from the 2nd value? Here is the code.

```
records = cursor.fetchall()
print(records)
('billtest1407337726531', '\x00')
records1 = curson.fetchall()
print(records1)
('billtest1407337726531', '\x01')
```

I need to store the value 0 or 1 from above tuples records and records1

I tried as below but it isn't working.

```
for row in records
   print(row[1])
   print((tuple(row[1:1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `ord(records[1])` to take the second value and convert it from a string to an integer (not parse, just convert the byte).

Comment: Many thanks .That worked well . But some sql queries I get below tuple values as                                   (('rmstprodtest14075645', '\x01'),)   . How to extract from this .

Comment: @user1726453: `ord(rec[0][1])` I guess.

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem, please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left.  Welcome to SO.